# VBA - Looping from two data lists and copying the matches

Tags: excel, vba

I have two lists of data in different sheets. Sheet 1 contains data from all across USA and Sheet 2 only contains data from one region. I need the macro to look for all the names that appear in Sheet 2 in Sheet 1, and copy all of them in a different sheet("FL"). My current macro only allows to specify on range and look for it in Sheet 1, instead I need to be able to select the whole list or column and do the same for all the different names.

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()


Dim Name As String
Dim i As Integer 'row counter


Sheets("FL").Range("A2:J5000").ClearContents
Name = Sheets("Sheets2"). Range("B2").Value 'I need that instead of B2 it loops through the end of the list B2:B5000

For i = 2 To 5000

    If Cells(i, 2) = Name Then
    
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 9)).Copy
    
        Sheets("FL").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        
        
        End If
        
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FL").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need another loop. FYI - I would not recommend using `Name` as a variable - you should use a word that isn't a common property in VBA.

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()

    Dim Name As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Sheets("FL").Range("A2:J5000").ClearContents
    
    For i = 2 To 5000
        
        Name = Sheets("Sheets2").Range("B" & i).Value
        
        For j = 2 To 5000
        
            If Cells(j, 2) = Name Then
            
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 9)).Copy
            
                Sheets("FL").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                
            End If
        
        Next j
            
    Next i
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FL").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: What about [using SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692882(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead of 4999*4999 (~25.000.000) cell = name comparisons? Also those implicit `Cells`calls are dangerous (implicit AcriveSheet.Cells what may change).